# Spring framework + Hazelcast , how to enable/disable cache using @Cacheable annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I am using Spring framework and hazelcast cache to cache REST APi at service layer. The api I am caching has @Cacheable annotation with cachename and keygenerator which works fine. I am looking for best way to enable/disable caching using application property or consul property. For that I am trying to pass the property in condition attribute of @Cachable annotation but is not working.  With this approach I will end up passing same value in multiple place (wherever I am caching at API level). Is there any good way to handle such operation. 
As an example here is a code snippet

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheName.MyCache1,keyGenerator = "customKeyGen")
public CachingObject myFirstAPI(String param1, String param2) {
}
```

Here the hazelcast cache will use customKeyGen and put value (CachingObject) returned by myFirstAPI . If I have to disable this operation , my current approach is to pass some value (read from application property) as condition so that it evaluate the flag/condition before creating cache and cache the value only if the condition is true i.e. cache is enabled, e.g.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheName.MyCache1,keyGenerator = "customKeyGen", condition="${enableCache}")
public CachingObject myFirstAPI(String param1, String param2) {
}
```

In my case the expression language I am passing in condition throwing exception , which I will figure out why (It is currently throwing SpelEvaluationException, Property or field 'enableCache' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' )

My question is , is this correct way to enable/disable caching ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `spring.cache.type` == `none`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-none

Comment: This solve my issue . I have added (bootstrap.yml) spring.cache.type=NONE to test that it disable caching.